# Faster way to process xml file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, iteration

I have this xml file named flight-itinerary.xml. A scaled-down version is shown below.

```
<itin line="1" dep="LOS" arr="ABV">
    <flt>
        <fltav>
            <cb>1</cb>
            <id>C</id>
            <av>10</av>
            <cur>NGN</cur>
            <CurInf>2,0.01,0.01</CurInf>
            <pri>15000.00</pri>
            <tax>30800.00</tax>
            <fav>1</fav>
            <miles></miles>
            <fid>11</fid>
            <finf>0,0,1</finf>

            <cb>2</cb>
            <id>J</id>
            <av>10</av>
            <cur>NGN</cur>
            <CurInf>2,0.01,0.01</CurInf>
            <pri>13000.00</pri>
            <tax>26110.00</tax>
            <fav>1</fav>
            <miles></miles>
            <fid>12</fid>
            <finf>0,0,0</finf>
        </fltav>
    </flt>
</itin>
```

The complete file contains 8 itinerary `<itin>` elements. The `<fltav>` element of each of the `<itin>` elements contains 11 of the `<cb>1</cb>` to `<finf>0,0,1</finf>` groups.

And below is the code I am using to process the file:

```
<?php

function processFlightsData()
{
    $data = array();
    $dom= new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('flight-itinerary.xml');

    $classbands  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('classbands')->item(0);
    $bands       = $classbands->getElementsByTagName('band');
    $itineraries = $dom->getElementsByTagName('itin');
    $counter     = 0;

    foreach($itineraries AS $itinerary)
    { 
        $flt = $itinerary->getElementsByTagName('flt')->item(0);

        $dep = $flt->getElementsByTagName('dep')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $arr = $flt->getElementsByTagName('arr')->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $time_data       = $flt->getElementsByTagName('time')->item(0);
        $departure_day   = $time_data->getElementsByTagName('ddaylcl')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $departure_time  = $time_data->getElementsByTagName('dtimlcl')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $departure_date  = $departure_day. ' '. $departure_time;
        $arrival_day     = $time_data->getElementsByTagName('adaylcl')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $arrival_time    = $time_data->getElementsByTagName('atimlcl')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $arrival_date    = $arrival_day. ' '. $arrival_time;
        $flight_duration = $time_data->getElementsByTagName('duration')->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $flt_det       = $flt->getElementsByTagName('fltdet')->item(0);
        $airline_id    = $flt_det->getElementsByTagName('airid')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $flt_no        = $flt_det->getElementsByTagName('fltno')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $flight_number = $airline_id. $flt_no;
        $airline_type  = $flt_det->getElementsByTagName('eqp')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $stops         = $flt_det->getElementsByTagName('stp')->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $av_data = $flt->getElementsByTagName('fltav')->item(0);

        $cbs     = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('cb')); //11 entries
        $ids     = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('id')); //ditto
        $seats   = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('av')); //ditto
        $curr    = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('cur')); //ditto
        $price   = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('pri')); //ditto
        $tax     = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('tax')); //ditto
        $miles   = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('miles')); //ditto
        $fid     = iterator_to_array($av_data->getElementsByTagName('fid')); //ditto    

        $inner_counter = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)
        {
            $data[$counter][$inner_counter] = array
            (
                'flight_number'                   => $flight_number,
                'flight_duration'                 => $flight_duration, 
                'departure_date'                  => $departure_date,
                'departure_time'                  => substr($departure_time, 0, 5),
                'arrival_date'                    => $arrival_date,
                'arrival_time'                    => substr($arrival_time, 0, 5),
                'departure_airport_code'          => $dep,
                'departure_airport_location_name' => get_airport_data($dep, $data_key='location'),
                'arrival_airport_code'            => $arr,
                'arrival_airport_location_name'   => get_airport_data($arr, $data_key='location'),
                'stops'                           => $stops,
                'cabin_class'                     => $ids[$i]->nodeValue,
                'ticket_class'                    => $ids[$i]->nodeValue,
                'ticket_class_nicename'           => formate_ticket_class_name($ids[$i]->nodeValue),
                'available_seats'                 => $seats[$i]->nodeValue,
                'currency'                        => $curr[$i]->nodeValue,
                'price'                           => $price[$i]->nodeValue,
                'tax'                             => $tax[$i]->nodeValue,
                'miles'                           => $miles[$i]->nodeValue,
            );

            ++$inner_counter;
        }

    return $data;
}

?>
```

Now, the outer loop iterates 8 times for each `<itin>` element, and during each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop iterates 11 times, resulting in a total of 88 iterations per pass and causing serious performance issues. What I am looking for is a faster method of processing the file. Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you experiencing performance issues or are you just interested in simplifying your loop(s)?

Comment: @Alasjo, I am experiencing performance issues. The entire thing takes like 100 seconds to execute.

Comment: I don't think the loop is the bottle-neck. What operation do you think is causing the performance issue? `get_airport_data`? `formate_ticket_class_name`?

Comment: @Alasjo, the loop is where the issue is coming from. I did benchmarks for each stage. Without the inner loop, the whole thing takes about 7 seconds to process. Once the loop is introduced, it takes minimum of a 100 seconds. If you know of a better way to simplify the loop and scaling down processing time, please help.

Comment: Trying your code (without the auxiliary operations) on a number of `itin` elements takes less than a second, check this fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7fpi-b3ka
Note that the XML might not be similar to yours, I've guessed a lot of elements that were missing.

Comment: You are right, I removed the auxiliary operations and tried the code. It execution time was around 30 seconds. One of those auxiliary operations calls a web service, and that's where the bottle neck was coming from.

Comment: Any way to call the web service with bulk data? Or cache the responses?

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can set it as the accepted answer? It did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the loop is the bottle-neck. You should check your operations that are called within the loop, `get_airport_data` and `formate_ticket_class_name`.

Trying your code (without the auxiliary operations) on a number of `itin` elements takes less than a second, check this fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7fpi-b3ka (Note that the XML might not be similar to yours, I've guessed a lot of elements that were missing).

If there are operations that are called which increases the processing time substantially, try to call the operation with bulk data or cache the responses.